# What are some good resources for learning about document oriented databases?

Tags: learning, nosql, document-oriented

I'm interested in learning about NoSQL databases and I decided to start with document oriented databases.  What are some good resources to learn the concepts and good design of this type of database?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good article comparing document oriented databases:

http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/09/01/comparing-document-oriented-databases/

and here's a good article about designing document oriented databases:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/08/designing-a-document-database.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Try these articles..

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/978742866/document-databases-compared-couchdb-mongodb-ravendb

http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/17/document-databases-compared-mongodb-couchdb-and-ravendb.aspx